# Animating Modal Appear/Hide

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a modal that is displayed when the `props.hidden` property is set to `true` and shown when it isn't.

Because I want the show/hide state to animate I need to first change the opacity of the modal to `0`, then turn off the `hidden` css property and finally change the opacity to `100`.

Likewise, when hiding the model, I need to change the opacity back to `0` first, and only then can I assign the `hidden` css property.

To take care of this I'm using two state vars `props.hidden` and `actualHidden`.
`props.hidden` refers to the target state of the modal of whether it should be hidden or not (after transition) whereas `actualHidden` captures whether the CSS `hidden` property should be applied.

I have implemented a `useEffect` hook to keep track of `props.hidden` and adjust `actualHidden` accordingly (with introduced delays to not cut off an animation short).

The code works well when hiding the modal, but for some reason does not animate the appearing of the modal (instead just makes the modal appear instantaneously).

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

**Modal.js**

```
export default function Modal(props) {
    const [actualHidden, setActualHidden] = useState(true)
    useEffect(() => {
        if(props.hidden === false) {
            setActualHidden(false)
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(() => setActualHidden(true), 300)
        }
    }, [props.hidden])

    return (
    <>
        <div
        className={`fixed ${props.hidden ? "opacity-0" : "opacity-100"} ${actualHidden ? "hidden" : ""} inset-0 bg-gray-600 bg-opacity-50 overflow-y-auto h-full w-full transition-all duration-300`}
        onClick={() => props.setHidden(true)}
        >
            additional modal html...
        </div>
    </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's because you set the opacity to 1 before the component has mounted.  So the css property isnt going from 0 to 1, it just starts at 1 and so the transition doesnt fire. Try setting both properties at the same time in the same fn without relying on the useEffect.
Eg having setHidden(false) and setActualHidden("") in the same fn.

Alternatively use a fade in keyframes css animation on the modal so it fades in whenever it mounts.

EDIT: Here is an example of what I mean.  You have to handle fading out the div manually, but you don't need to fade the component in as the animation css property will handle that whenever the div mounts. Example: (Note the css is in index.html):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-r5bqg7?file=src%2FApp.js
App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [display, setDisplay] = React.useState('none');
  const [opacity, setOpacity] = React.useState(1);

  const toggleVisibility = () => {
    if (display === 'none') {
      setDisplay('');
      setOpacity(1)
    } else {
      setOpacity(0);
      setTimeout(() => setDisplay('none'), 3000);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="box" style={{ display, opacity }}>
        Hello
      </div>
      <button onClick={toggleVisibility}>Toggle Visibility</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

index.html

```
<style>
  @keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  .box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    transition: opacity 3s;
    animation: fadeIn 3s;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I don't think it has much to do with setting the opacity to `1` before mounting. I outputted the classNames to console on button click and after and could see it go from `opacity-0 hidden` to `opacity-100`

Comment: Regarding the keyframes, that takes care of animating the opacity, but isn't that the same as my manual `opacity-0` `opacity-100` classes? This doesn't take care of hiding the component if I understand correctly. The component must be hidden so that it doesn't interfere with other elements on the page

Comment: Correct you still manually set the opacity to hide the component, but the css animation will take care of the fade in whenever the display is shown again.  I have edited an example to my answer.